# How can I unit test http handler embedded in a struct?

Tags: go

I have the following struct

```
type Server struct {
        *http.Server
        chain      core.Blockchainer
        coreServer *network.Server
    }
```

with its corresponding `handler`

```
func (s *Server) methodHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *Request, reqParams Params) {
.....
}
```

How can I unit test my `handler`?

Comment: The same way like any other function - invoke it.

Comment: Sorry, I did mean unit test. Basically I would like to use `httptest.Server` in the `Server`struct but this is not possible. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Hi @DTT, have you figured out a way yet? I'm happy to explain if you need some help still

Comment: Thanks RuNpiXelruN for asking. Yes I was able to test my handler using  `httptest.NewRequest` and `httptest.NewRecorder`. But would be happy to know if the handler can be tested also with `httptest.Server`

Answer (score 0):

The handler above

```
func (s *Server) methodHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *Request, reqParams Params) {
.....
}
```

can be tested by following these steps

```
handler := http.HandlerFunc(s.methodHandler)

req := httptest.NewRequest(...) 

w := httptest.NewRecorder()

handler(w, req)

resp := w.Result()

assert.Equal(t, expected, resp)
```